# Forgot Password MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

In my application I am trying to get a forgot password to work. I am trying to send an email to the user when he/she inputs his or her user name, sends them and email, they click on that link, and are brought back into the website and changes their password. Only thing is that my linq query is  wrong an is not checking to see if the username exists in the database. Is this the right way to go by getting a forget password to work?

Here is my code

Controller

```
    // GET: /Account/ForgotPassword
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ForgetPassword()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Post: /Account/ForgotPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ForgetPassword(ForgetPasswordModel model, string UserName)
    {
        string emailAddress = (from i in db.UserProfiles
                                where i.UserName.Equals(model.Username)
                                select i.Email).Single();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailAddress))
        {
            string confirmationToken =
                WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(model.Username);
            dynamic email = new Email("ChngPasswordEmail");
            email.To = emailAddress;
            email.UserName = model.Username;
            email.ConfirmationToken = confirmationToken;
            email.Send();

            return RedirectToAction("ResetPwStepTwo");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("InvalidUserName");
    }
```

Model

```
public class ForgetPasswordModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model MyFestival.Models.UserProfile
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Forgot Password";
}

<hr />
<div class="form-group">
  <h3 class="panel-title">Did you forget your password?</h3>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())


{
<div class="">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
    <hr />
    <label>To reset your password, input your email address and press the Reset Password button.</label>
    <br/>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <div class="col-md-12" >
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" ></i ></span >
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Username" })
            </div >
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10" >
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"  value="Reset Password"/ >
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to Login", "Login", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
        </div >
    </div>
</div>


}
```

Comment: currently what is happening??

Comment: Then create a query to check if Username exist?

Comment: when it comes to here:

`string emailAddress = (from i in db.UserProfiles where i.UserName.Equals(model.Username) select i.Email).Single();`

Example, I use my username and it doesn't check to see if the username exist in the database. And tells me that my username doesn't exist in the database, which it does.

Comment: If email address will not exist in the databases it will `RedirectToAction("InvalidUserName");` which is desired. As I understand this is what you want,right?

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly goes wrong in your solution? The query to check if username exists? If yes, you can try to profile the SQL quuery that is generated by your ORM. Additionally it might be useful to use another overload of `Equals`: `i.UserName.Equals(model.Username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: I tried `i.UserName.Equals(model.Username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` @takemyoxygen but it is still not searching the database for the username I input.

Comment: Is there any other way I can get this to work? I dot know why the application is not picking up the username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just spotted that you have both `ForgetPasswordModel model` and `string username` as arguments of your controller action and later you use `Username` property of your model. I assume that Model Binder just initializes the `stirng username` instead of `ForgegPasswordModel`. Could you try removing `stirng username` - the second parameter of `ForgetPassword` action?

Comment: Could you please confirm that `model.Username` has exactly the same value that was entered on the webpage? The next step is to verify the SQL query that your ORM generates. You can use SQL Server Management Studio to do that, just go to Tools -> SQL Server Profiler, connect to your database, start profiling session and then submit your webpage. You should see a SQL query in the profiler window.

Comment: The username I input, yes its the same with model.Username. The next step you tell me to do, I can't do that because the option is not available in my SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: One more thing came to my mind. You can play with LINQPad (https://www.linqpad.net/) to debug your query, just check if it will work there. By the way, using `Single` is a bit destructive - it will throw an exception every time you have no users with given names. Consider using `SingleOrDefault` instead.

Comment: Sorry @takemyoxygen, made a stupid error, there was no email address in the database, under my username! Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own GUID and send it with email to user.
When user click on email link check Guid and update new password of user.

Here is the sample code

Create a view to enter forgot password email

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Forgot Password";
}

<h2>Forgot Password</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
   <div class="form-horizontal">
  <hr />
   <div class="text-success">
      @ViewBag.Message
   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    Please enter your registered email address below to receive an email containing a link, to reset your password.
   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-md-2">Email Address</label>
       @Html.TextBox("EmailID", "", new { @class = "form-control" })
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
 }
```

Then in your Controller get Email id from user, check if email exists and create new GUID, save it in database, send email to user.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword(string EmailID)
    {
        string resetCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var verifyUrl = "/Account/ResetPassword/" + resetCode;

        var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, verifyUrl);
       //get user details from database.
        using (var context = new LoginRegistrationInMVCEntities())
        {
            var getUser = (from s in context.RegisterUsers where s.Email == EmailID select s).FirstOrDefault();
            if (getUser != null)
            {
                getUser.ResetPasswordCode = resetCode;

                //This line I have added here to avoid confirm password not match issue , as we had added a confirm password property 

                context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
                context.SaveChanges();

                var subject = "Password Reset Request";
                var body = "Hi " + getUser.FirstName + ", <br/> You recently requested to reset your password for your account. Click the link below to reset it. " +

                     " <br/><br/><a href='" + link + "'>" + link + "</a> <br/><br/>" +
                     "If you did not request a password reset, please ignore this email or reply to let us know.<br/><br/> Thank you";

                SendEmail(getUser.Email, body, subject);

                ViewBag.Message = "Reset password link has been sent to your email id.";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "User doesn't exists.";
                return View();
            }
        }

        return View();
    }

    private void SendEmail(string emailAddress, string body, string subject)
    {
        using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("youremail@gmail.com", emailAddress))
        {
            mm.Subject = subject;
            mm.Body = body;

            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("youremail@gmail.com", "YourPassword");
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mm);

        }
    }
```

Now, when user click on the email and enter new password, check Guid with what we have saved in database and update password if guid matches.

Check for more info:

[Forgot password functionality in ASP.NET MVC (Reset password by Email)](https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp-net/implementing-forgot-password-functionality-in-aspnet-mvc-res/218)